# Decimal Places using double with toString, android

Tags: android, double, tostring

I am creating a simple program that performs simple math functions on the values a user enters in the EditText views. The first two EditText views contain integers and the last could be a decimal, thus the answer could also need to be in decimal form so I set the and (vis) as a double, but how can I limit the decimal places to four? Everything is running fine, the answer is just many decimal places long!

Here is my code:

```
public void onClick(View v) {
            String a,b,t;
            double vis;

            EditText txtbox1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.A);
                EditText txtbox2 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.B);
                EditText txtbox3 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.t);
                TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Answer);

            a = txtbox1.getText().toString();
            b = txtbox2.getText().toString();
            t = txtbox3.getText().toString();

            vis = ((Integer.parseInt(a)*1) + (Integer.parseInt(b)*2)) /       (Double.parseDouble(t));
            tv.setText(double.toString(vis));       
    }
}
```

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 12):

You could use `String.format()` to make sure you only get 4 decimal places in your output. Simply replace the last line with `tv.setText(String.format("%.4f", vis));`.

See http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/numberformat.html for more details on how to use `String.format()` for this purpose.

Answer (score 2):

I think it's a bit too late to answer, but it may help for future purpose.

If we have a `double` number and we need to get the 4 decimal values we can multiply the `double` by 10000, and cast the `double` value into an `integer` and reverse into `double` again and divide the digit by 10000.

Answer (score 1):

For more control, use `BigDecimal.round()`. You can set a `MathContext` with the precision and rounding rule you require (.5 is round up, vs .5 is rounded down, etc).

```
double vis = 21.23456;

tv.setText(new BigDecimal(vis).round(new MathContext(6, RoundingMode.HALF_UP)).toString());
```